# Test AutoCAD 3D images using selenium or some java library

Tags: java, selenium, 3d, automation, autocad

My application involves 3D and 2D diagrams. I want to test 3D/2D diagrams(comparison,crop/color/isolation of different parts in 3d model) using selenium web driver. If it's not suitable, Can somebody please suggest a best open source tool that would be helpful in designing my automation scripts to test images? It is java code based, then it's more helpful as i'm familiar with java.Or is there any JAVA API to test images/cropped/parts of the 3d images or models?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

anyways..i found myself a way to solve this issue.. i used java script(code which was taken from the same page activex asp file) to get the "viewstate" xml file that has that activex object's state values. I have done operations on that and now, i am able to manipulate it..it's the best to work with activex objects i guess as QTP is doing the same thing.Last but not least, one must have to select the frame in which activex object is embedded.then only we will be able to run that script successfully. cheers!!